# Weird Crash using application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I developed an application. It was working perfectly fine until recently but sometimes it gives the below error and it crashes. There is no line number or other infor where the error occurred, so I am not sure what to look for:

```
 See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Any clues or ideas what it might be? Basically it is a scraper and poster sometime it would go over 80k and work nicely and finish some time it gives the error as above ?

Let me know if any one has faced similar issue as I clearly cannot find out why!

**UPDATE**

One reason I can think of is the tool have approx 10 `Listview` control on the form and it stores info and display approximately all of them go over 50 k. But again sometimes it  will go over 80k and sometimes it would pop the error maybe on 1k. And this was working perfectly fine, I never saw this error for more than 5-6 months. This just started happening.

**UPDATE**

Another weird thing i just noticed is when I click the bot anywhere: this error popups now after a random time. So not sure what is wrong with it. Supposing I have a `Listview`, when I go in there to see the URLs I see the error as below ,others are working fine and after that clicking anywhere brings in this error.

And on searching I also found this [Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jclarknet/archive/2006/05/02/444845.aspx). This perfectly matches to my scenario `Listview` in `tabcontrol` and it states here it's a bug.

This is how i am inserting to `ListView` :

```
           ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(url, 0);
              if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
                 {
                   listView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                      () =>
                   listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 })
                                        ));
                 }
              else
                {
                  listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 });
                }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You've shown us a a null ref error message but haven't given us any details about your code - it's going to be nearly impossible to work out where it's coming from!

Comment: @Liath that is the issue i am not sure where it is coming from. Everything is in try catch and checked for null still this error popup up, i read the article above stating its a bug if listview is in tabcontrol maybe it is that.

Comment: Turn on break on exception and disable just my code?

Comment: @Liath not sure what you mean either i am not familiar with that or i did not understand you properly.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/25/understanding-just-my-code.aspx

Comment: @Liath   ty, testing it out now the run sometime show this on 1000 something not even on 80 k records searched so testing it now /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListView.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
```

This is **framework code**. This is **not** your code. All from the stack-root to the crash is in the framework. This tells almost nothing about the cause, sorry.

From my experience, it's not easy to get a crash during OnHandleCreated. I've seen it a few times, and it was usually due to:

- some other thread-race in completely different part of code
- some eventhandler tries to reload/build the UI during the Form's Close or Dispose
- some eventhandler tries to reload/build the UI before the Form's normal startup
- ill-written P/Invoke code (trying to "hack" the control to achieve some nonstandard look or behavior)

I've looked at `ListView.OnHandleCreated` in a decompiler, and I have not noticed any easy ways to get an NullReference there.. For example, having a `null` in its `.Items` or `.columnHeaders` could to it, but it's not so easy to have a null there, as the ListView manages those collections internally. However, I do not see any locks, so if a thread-race occurred, it could be it.

Is it a normal ListView, or did you subclass it and override something?

EDIT:

The OnHandleCreated is strange.. By default, the Handle is created on the first time when the control becames visible. If you have **any** show/hide behavior, and if the ListView is not visible at form's startup when the threads are starting up, the issue may be very subtle.

The OnHandleCreated is a callback from native part of the control's implementation. I don't see any locks/synchros in the code. If the ListView's real-initialization was delayed, and if the threads started up pumping the data, then I **guess** that **maybe** the native callback came into a race with your worker thread pushing a new data item into the Items.

Try forcing the ListView's Handle to be created earlier, much earlier. Find your InitializeComponent function, and add a dummy line after it, and **before** the start of the threads:

```
myFormConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var foo = myListView.Handle;

    onlyNowStartTheThreads();
}
```

It will cause the application to start creating the Handle immediatelly and **wait** until it has completed. I'm not sure about the exact race point, but it will at least exclude the possibility of that one.

Comment: It's a simple ListView , however data is stored in it using multiple threads. But this same piece of code ran perfectly fine for over 6 months than suddenly this error shows up randomly .

Comment: @confusedMind: Do you use `InvokeRequired / BeginInvoke / Invoke` to operate on the ListView from those threads, or have you turned off the CrossThread checks?

Comment: Yes i am using InvokeRequired... see question above for update please.

Comment: Is that ListView constructed once during InitializeComponent and stays there, or do you re-create it sometimes due to some reasons? Does it crash during the Window's startup, or later whlie the window is visible and work is being done? If the latter, can you guess why the ListView would try "creating its handle" again (if it was ever visible, then it was already created. having OnhandleCreated during work is strange)? Do you have any dynamic panels that get initialized "later" during work?

Comment: No, InvokeRequired/BeginInvoke is OK. It's good you have not turned off the XThread checks, that would enable you to perform so many more races..

Comment: HI, Sometime it would go though 80 k records and wont crash sometime maybe on 100 , its random. So i cannot figure out the root. I do this on form_load :

  listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
            listView1.LabelEdit = true;
            listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
            listView1.GridLines = true;
After that it's the simple insert and i clear ListView if it goes over 200 item etc.

Comment: However at a point i open up an alert form on top of my form and do something than close it and come back to main form i believe that wont fire the form load etc .

Comment: No, the Form.Load does not fire multiple times, it is called only once at first show up. Then, only OnActivated or OnFocus (I dont remember) are called. Please see my update and try it

Comment: Also one more point the listview are inside tabcontrol , i also read an article stating that its a bug. SO maybe going off a tabpage and coming back in does that?

Comment: i have done that but the campaign takes hour to run so i will run it and see how it goes and will update.

Comment: Yes, TabControl can easily influence that. If the LV is on a TabPage that is not the DEFAULT TabPage, then the LV is **not created** until you open its tab. The native controls are by default created on the first time they are **actually** displayed - that's when their 'handles' are allocated and then the OnHandleCreated event occurs.

Comment: doing that will take hours to see how it goes will update you .

Comment: okok, I was just responding to your previous questions in the comments :)

Comment: one last thing to confirm i just write this line:

var foo = listview1.Handle;
var foo2 = listview2.Handle;....

For all the listview in the tabcontrol that's it ? The remaining code remains the same.

Comment: yes, just that. Read all the Handles to ListViews that sit on any panel that can be switched between visible-and-notvisible. Just reading the `Handle` property is enough, you can immediatelly forget the obtained value.

Comment: working nicely so far :) looks like it worked.

Answer (score 2):

With the information you provide all I can say is that you're trying to access an object that probably got disposed or you removed, either intentionaly or unintentionally, usually NullReferenceExceptions are easy to look for while debuggin inside Visual Studio. Look for any piece of code that is trying to read/write from an object that COULD be NULL in a given situation.

Comment: I reviewed the code again and checked all for null before inserting into listview and put it in try catch now one thing is it does show the error above but does not crash  i can continue and move forward but how to totally avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

To find out where the error occurs you can (often) use "Break on exception" to let the debugger stop at the line of code where the error occurs. (Makes debugging a lot easier, but can be annoying if you handle a lot of errors correctly as it stops then as well).

1. To turn it on, open the "debug" menu an click on "Exceptions..." (Ctrl+D+E as shortcut)
2. Activate the "Common Language Runtime Exception" in the "Thrown" column.
3. Click "OK" and start the application again and let the error occur. Now the debugger will stop at the line of code it was found (probably).